# MVC2 - Custom MembershipProvider Implementation Isn't Found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, web-config, membership-provider

Despite finding several references to this problem on the web, I have been unable to find a solution.

I have a custom MembershipProvider called ConfigMembershipProvider in the `Config.Web.Areas.Accounts.Providers` namespace.  The assembly name is `Config.Web`.

My web.config looks like this:

```
<membership defaultProvider="ConfigMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="ConfigMembershipProvider"
             type="Config.Web.Areas.Accounts.Providers.ConfigMembershipProvider, 
                   Config.Web"
             applicationName="Configurator"
             connectionStringName="Test_User_and_RolesConnectionString"/>
     </providers>
</membership>
```

The error message I am getting is `Parser Error Message: Default Membership Provider could not be found.`

I cannot figure out why it cannot find the default membership provider... any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Scott.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what happened, but I created another Membership Provider & literally copy/pasted the contents from each method in the original to the new one, changed web.config file to reflect the new name and everything works.

Crazy, but true.

Answer (score 0):

Looks okay .

Not sure but looking at syntax -

try removing                     ****Config.Web"****

type="Config.Web.Areas.Accounts.Providers.ConfigMembershipProvider, 
 **Config.Web**"

Answer (score 0):

Is this the root web.config? Could a web.config in a lower directory be clearing the membership provider?